# Sharing PATH across login mechanisms with modification support

Tags: paths

I'm running Xubuntu 14.10, currently using lightdm. Let's examine two process trees:

```
init───lightdm───lightdm───upstart───xfce4-terminal───bash
```

and:

```
init───lightdm───lightdm───upstart───emacs─┬─{dconf worker}
                                           ├─{gdbus}
                                           └─{gmain}
```

My issue is that I am setting PATH in `.bashrc`, which given that emacs is started by upstart (using the keyboard shortcut), makes it not have the same PATH value. (I know I should move that to `.bash_profile` or so, but that won't fix the issue and it's fine given that I usually login in one way only, through X / lightdm.)

Consider these three cases:

- Terminal on vty1 -> bash - path is initialized by bash (`.bash_profile`)
- X -> emacs - path is initialized by lightdm (`.xinitrc`)
- X -> xfce4-terminal -> bash - path is initialized by lightdm (`.xinitrc`), then modified by bash (`.bash_profile`)

First - is the above correct or are there other things happening? Or better yet - should I be using the above to initialize or some other files / mechanisms?

If the above is correct, I assume putting PATH in a script, then calling from both `.bash_profile` and `.xinitrc` would be the best way to sync up all these environments, correct?

Are there hooks that provide a way to reset the PATH of lightdm? I'd like to avoid logging in and out when changing PATH if possible.

Comment: ... how is `emacs` started? It should run with your user, and the only sane thing I can imagine is doing `lightdm` is calling  it through a `su youruser whatever` that should run a shell which should read at least `.profile`. But I can be wrong, use `-u` option to `pstree` to show where the change of users are.